# DDD: How should domain events access web request data?

Tags: model-view-controller, domain-driven-design

Say that our `Analytics` model subscribes to `CommentPosted` event and wants to record posted comment ID against a tracker cookie of a request that posted the said comment. Unfortunately our `CommentPosted` event does not know anything about HTTP request as it only has reference to the posted comment.

To solve this, in our listener we could use DI to get current request and use that to retrieve needed cookie from there. However, this tightly couples our Domain to a Web tier.

Another way would be to ask Controller to pass needed cookie to `CommentingService` that will in turn call `AnalyticsService` with the cookie. But now the commenting system has to mediate for analytics.

Isn't there a better way to plug this in without commenting knowing anything about analytics and without domain knowing anything about web tier?

Comment: why doesn't your CommentPosted event contain the trackerId?

Comment: Because Comment does not have concept of tracker in its domain. When CommentPosted event is raised it contains only the posted comment.

Comment: What exactly is `tracker` concept? Is this a person, who submitted the comment or something else?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Please see my comment to Stephan Eggermont's answer.

Comment: If trackerID is just ID of person who submitted comment. Why your CommentPosted event doesn't have person's id? You do not keep information about who posted an comment?

Comment: If unregistered users comment then I only keep their email.

Comment: And how you want to track unregistered users, if you don't even know who are they?

Comment: By a long living cookie. I know it's not perfect, but it works a long as user doesn't delete his cookie. It is sufficient for my use case.

Comment: @DenisPshenov I guess you're lacking domain object in your model then. 
You probably should implement "Anonymous Author" or something like that. In CommentWasPosted Event you will have his ID.

You should talk with your Domain Experts about such situation and ask them what to do. They should inform you, if something like "Anonymous Author" exists within Comment's Bounded Context.

Comment: Yes we do have anonymous author concept but we only identify them by email. The tracker thing is analytics concern and commenting doesn't care or need it. The point I was trying to convey is how can we keep this separation without having to introduce trackerId concept into our anonymous user in comments.

Comment: I have not found a proper solution and opted to include trackerId in the comment model if it is made by anonymous user. The thing is that when we decide not to use analytics anymore we will probably forget to remove now useless trackerId concept from the comment model.

Comment: @DenisPsherov Still maybe you should have one more author object? Unregistered Author would be identified by email and anonymous by some ID (and it would be trackerID).  You're talking about such user -anonymous, but maybe you didn't even realized it "if it is made by anonymous user".

Comment: + You wouldn't need to create entity for such authors. They can be simple value objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like some part of analytics needs to part of your domain. What does analytics do for you in domain terms?

Comment: It tracks visitors using a long living cookie and records their usage for later analysis. Are you saying that my comment model should have a trackerId also?

Comment: I chose your answer as correct because I ended up doing just that. However I am still not completely satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your main domain unaware of the Analytics subdomain and vice versa, you could have an interceptor/request processor at the controller level that captures http information as well as a generic Command data structure containing info about the action the user is doing. The interceptor could then call an Analytics application service directly or publish an event with these details for analytics purposes.

Things start getting a bit more complex if you want to track not just characteristics shared by all commands across your application but also more specific domain-level details. In particular ones that are only known after the domain operation completes (such as a newly posted `CommentId`).

- Your Comment application service could return `NewCommentId` to the Controller after the command completes and it could be relayed to the interceptor, but that isn't really compliant with the concept of a Command from CQRS.
- Another option would be to have some correlation ID between an analytics tracking session and domain actions taken by the user during that session. That pivot could be Commands. The Analytics interceptor persists `CommandId` along with all http-derived information it wants and when the domain aggregate publishes the `CommentPosted` event, it can include the originating `CommandId` in the event. If `AnalyticsService` subscribes to this event, it will be able to relate it back to the session (trackerId) the command was part of.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. Will try to investigate into your suggestions further.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple services can subscribe to an event. The analyticsService could subscribe to the CommentPostedEvent. That way you avoid having the CommentService be dependent on the analyticservice. the analyticsservice could then go figure out what else it needs (like getting the orignal request).

What you could even do is define a more generic HttpTrackingEvent and have that raised as well when a post is being done with the cookie that you desire. (not just for comments but for any httppost with the right tracking id) Then the AnalyticsService could subscribe to that event and (hopefully) figure out you were creating a new comment.